# Converting KerasTensor to numpy array

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, eager-execution

I am trying to convert "KerasTensor" into numpy array. I have tried converting KerasTensor to tf.Tensor (with no luck). I have also tried using tensor.numpy(), tensor.eval() and keras.backend.eval(tensor) all of that have not worked. Trying ".numpy()" and ".eval()" I am getting *AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'* error. How do I convert extracted KerasTensor to numpy array or to EagerTensor so I can use .numpy() method ?

Tensorflow version: 2.8.0
Keras version: 2.8.0

Thanks for help

Edit (Additional info): Model is build using keras functional API. After fit() I am extracting encoded input by: encoded = model.get_layer("encoder_output").output After that I've tried converting the "encoded" KerasTensor like I've described above and it does not work.

Comment: Can you show your code / your model?

Comment: I've changed it

Comment: Show all your code..Everything relevant to your problem.

Comment: A layer's `output` is a symbolic tensor with no data; you cannot convert this to a numpy array.

Comment: @xdurch0 then how can I extract values from that specific layer (after training the model)?

Comment: This has been asked and answered before, please ask about your actual problem and not about what you think the solution is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no value to convert to numpy.

You need an input to have an output.

In keras, the best to do is to build a submodel.

```
submodel = Model(original_model.inputs, original_model.get_layer("encoder_output").output)   
results = submodel.predict(numpy_input)
```

Comment: I am not sure why you reopened the question and answered it, this has been asked and answered before, and your answer does not add anything new.